# Debian - add-apt-repository not found, software-properties-common not found

Tags: linux, debian, apt

I need to add new apt repositoty, but add-apt-repository command not found and when I'm trying to install **software-properties-common and python-software-properties**, only the **python-software-properties** is installed and that's not enough. *"Couldn't find package software-properties-common"* message is shown instead the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Try the builtin command [apt-add-repository](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/add-apt-repository.1.html).  Does the same thing, atleast in Ubuntu, and doesn't require an additional package.  Seems to be in 12.04 and newer of Ubuntu.